# How do I deduce inclusion exclusion formula from $I_A = S_1 -S_2 +\dots\pm S_n$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $I_i = I_{A_i}$ be the indicators of n events having union $A$. Let $S_k = \sum I_{i_1}\dots I_{i_k}$, where the summation extends over all $k$-tuple satisfying $1 \leq i_1 < i_2 <\dots<i_k \leq n$. Then $s_k=E[S_k]$ are the terms in the inclusion-exclusion formula $P(A)=s_1-s_2+\dots\pm s_n$. Deduce the inclusion-exclusion formula from $I_A = S_1 -S_2+\dots\pm S_n$. Prove that latter formula by expanding the product $\prod_{i=1}^n (1-I_i)$.

I am little confused in understanding the statement. Can anyone give me some hints how to solve this question?

Comment: Where is your own attempt?

Answer (score 2):

We want to compute $P(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)$. Let us compute the probability of $(A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_n)^c = A_1^c \cap \dots \cap A_n^c$ instead.
We have
\begin{align}
I_{A_1^c \cap \dots \cap A_n^c} &= I_{A_1^c}\dots I_{A_n^c} \\
&= (1 - I_{A_1})\dots(1 - I_{A_n}).
\end{align}
Now take expectations to get
$$P(A_1^c \cap \dots \cap A_n^c) = E((1 - I_{A_1})\dots(1 - I_{A_n})).$$
To compute the right hand side, expand the product $(1 - I_{A_1})\dots(1 - I_{A_n})$ into a sum of terms and then use linearity of expectation.